# Error while calling setPixel on displayed bitmap

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, imageview

I'm developing simple application, which should do some image processing and display progress to user. Because i want user to see the whole process, it's not possible to set bitmap to imageView after the process completes, or do the work in UI thread.

I ended up with following solution:

1. Obtain bitmap from source
2. Set bitmap to ImageView
3. Run image processing task on background thread (using `AsyncTask`)

Here is simplified source code:

```
public class ImageProcessingTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Void, Bitmap>
{
    private Listener listener = null;

    public ImageProcessingTask(Listener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Params... params)
    {
        // Do work, call setPixel in cycle without Thread.sleep() is enough
        ImageProcessing.processImage(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if(listener != null)
        {
            listener.onImageProcessingTaskPostExecute(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working just great, except once in a while in approximately in half of image (randomly) the process stops and i get this

`E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Cannot generate texture from bitmap`

In this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uh4UpvN_Be8) i find out that it is problem related to hardware acceleration, so i turned it off

```
imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

The problem disapeared from console, but everyting i achieved was that bitmap disapeared from ImageView on exactly same spot, instead of freezing.

I found several discussions throughout the internet, but i haven't discover any useful solutions to this problem. I tried to synchronize access to bitmap using `synchronized` statement and `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`, but with no success.

And last one interesting fact i noticed - i have simple color detection algorithm, that compute number of individual colors on picture. If i run it after image processing function, it returns different values, as if bitmap didn't change colors at all (physically, so it probably isn't just OpenGL problem).

List of approaches i used:

- Disable hardware acceleration for ImageView (see above)
- Synchronize access to bitmap (no change)
- setPixels instead of setPixel (no change)
- copyPixelsFromBuffer + copyPixelsToBuffer instead of setPixel (no change)
- move setPixel in UI thread using Handler (no change)
- much more...